# Do a publisher and a subscriber on the same machine incur network load?

Tags: ros, communication, serialization, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all :) I have a few questions regarding ROS network communication.

1. I have a Publisher and a Subscriber living on Machine A, with Machine B as the ROS Master. Do they still send messages over the network? If they do not, do the messages still get serialized and deserialized? (I wonder what really happens behind scenes)
2. Same as (1.), but now both Publisher and Subscriber live in the same node. Does it make any difference?
3. I'm aware of the concept of nodelets for accessing shared memory. Does the Publisher/Subscriber paradigm have any similar functionality?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346374/do-a-publisher-and-a-subscriber-on-the-same-machine-incur-network-load?/) by [JunTuck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26970/juntuck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2020-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have a Publisher and a Subscriber living on Machine A, with Machine B as the ROS Master. Do they still send messages over the network?

See #q276636 (also related: #q285336).

> If they do not, do the messages still get serialized and deserialized? [..] Now both Publisher and Subscriber live in the same node. Does it make any difference?

(de)serialisation *always* happens, no matter where publishers or subscribers "live", *unless* you're using nodelets.

> I'm aware of the concept of nodelets for accessing shared memory. Does the Publisher/Subscriber paradigm have any similar functionality?

This question is a bit strange: *both* nodes and nodelets contain publishers and subscribers. Zero-copy message exchange is not a property of subscribers or publishers, but of nodelets.

So: if the publisher *and* the subscriber exist in nodelets and share the same memory address space (ie: are loaded in the same nodelet manager), *then* zero-copy message exchange can be used.

Otherwise it's not possible.

There have been some shared-memory transports in the past, but they're unmaintained, and (almost certainly) incompatible with current ROS versions.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-10**:
PS: please refrain from posting multiple questions in a single question. The "other questions" have very poor visibility, as the title of your post does not cover them. ROS Answers is not a forum, but an AskBot instance, which works best with a 1-to-1 ratio of questions-to-answers.

In the future, post multiple questions (after making sure they do not already exist).

**Comment by [JunTuck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26970/juntuck/) on 2020-03-26**:
Thanks @gvdhoorn for the clear and concise response, as well as for the heads up about multiple questions. Noted for the future!